# IOS/Xcode: Safe to drag and drop images to Images.xcassets without adding first?

Tags: xcode, xcasset

Normally to add a file in Xcode, I first move it to the project directory and then click File Add to bring it into the project. The reason I first move it into the project directory is to avoid cases of accidentally moving or deleting a file that might be in downloads, the desktop or whatever.

However, with the imageset in images.xcassets, Xcode seems to let you just drag a file onto the placeholder spot and it automatically imports the image. I don't know where it really stores the image and I don't know if it stores it in a safe place. I've also noticed a few weird things like if you right click and open in finder, it has taken an image that was 25x25 and created one that is 26x26 or created a copy of an image that was 50x50 to 51x51. These appear in a folder called blank.imageset where blank is the name of the imageset. No idea why it does this.

I gather it's *possible* therefore to skip the steps of moving the file to the project directory and adding it.  I'm wondering if it there is any downside to skipping those steps, however.

Would appreciate any illumination on what's going on behind the scenes and whether it is safe to merely drag and drop from any random location.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to drag and drop images. I have been doing this since the feature showed up on XCode and haven't faced any problems. I just make sure that when I add images this way, I see that the next commit on my git repo includes these images added.

For this:

> It has taken an image that was 25x25 and created one that is 26x26 or
>   created a copy of an image that was 50x50 to 51x51.

I think the problem is usually with the image dimensions, where the image with 25x25 and 50x50 are actually 25.6x25.5 and 50.5x50.5, which show up as correct dimensions in your finder, but if you open it up in Sketch or Photoshop, you may see the real dimensions.

When you drop such images into Xcode, it shows the rounded up dimensions.

As a thumb rule, I try to get design assets that don't have such issues, by ensuring that the @1x image asset is a whole number, and @2x and @3x images are exact multiples. Its hard to believe how often I have received images that are not exact multiples, which still renders well, but sometimes can look blurry on a higher res screen due to mismatch. (this used to be obvious during 4S and iPhone 5 days).

Now that there's no need to design for @1x, since all devices are retina (unless you support older versions of iOS), the problem can happen even when designing assets at @2x also. The dimension of an @3x image will be 79.5x79.5 if @2x image is 53x53.

So if a designer is designing at @2x, its easy to forget that the @3x image will now have dimensions that may not be whole numbers.

Such assets will lead to issues where you think it is one dimension, and XCode shows an off by 1 pixel dimension.

About the blank.imageset

> These appear in a folder called blank.imageset where blank is the name of the imageset.
>   No idea why it does this.

Imageset name and the actual image names can be different, and when use use the imageset in your code, you are actually using the imageset name, not the individual image names.

You can have your images as `lion.png, animal@2x.png, cat@3x.png` and drop it into image assets folder, it'll create a `blank.imageset`. Tap that `blank.imageset` again, and you can rename it as `cat.imageset`. And you can use this image in your code as `.....imageNamed: "cats"......`

Answer (score 1):

I usually just drag&drop files into placeholders inside .xcassets file in Xcode. It is copied automatically, as you describe, so no need to add the image to the project prior that.

Have not experienced any resize though, probably you pick incorrect image size?

Comment: For tab bar controller icons, am using 25x25, 50,50 and 75x75 which I thought Apple recommends.  What are you supposed to use?

Comment: Better make a screenshot, what exact do you have in Xcode when opening .xcassets file, they may have several formats.